# 2^(p-1)-1 = 0 mod p^2

Tags: nt.number-theory

For the Prime p, 
if
2^(p-1)-1 = 0 mod p^2
 what are the conditions for p?

Thank you..

Comment: These are called Wieferich primes. You should have a look to the Wikipedia page about them.

Comment: No conditions are known yet.